# Constructor parameter in configuration class required a bean of type 'StratusAuthenticationEntryPoint' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

Parameter 0 of constructor in ResourceServerConfiguration required a bean of type 'StratusAuthenticationEntryPoint' that could not be found.

I am using spring boot 2.6.6
Here is the code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(100)
//@Import({ApiPermissionEvaluator.class})
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final StratusAuthenticationEntryPoint securityAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    public ResourceServerConfiguration(StratusAuthenticationEntryPoint securityAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
        super();
        this.securityAuthenticationEntryPoint = securityAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }
}
```

error message:

```
            ***************************
        APPLICATION FAILED TO START
        ***************************

        Description:

        Parameter 0 of constructor in com.stratus.security.config.ResourceServerConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.stratus.security.config.StratusAuthenticationEntryPoint' that c
        ould not be found.


        Action:

        Consider defining a bean of type 'com.stratus.security.config.StratusAuthenticationEntryPoint' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add @Component over Class of `StratusAuthenticationEntryPoint` that a bean created by spring ioc
2. verify if the `ComponentScan` path contains Class of `StratusAuthenticationEntryPoint`